# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using @react-oauth/google package.
Login.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import shareVideo from '../assets/share.mp4';
import logo from '../assets/logowhite.png';
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { client } from '../client';

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const responseGoogle=(response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj))

    const {name, googleId, imageUrl} = response.profileObj;
    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: 'user',
      image: imageUrl,
      userName: name,  
    }
    client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      .then(() =>{
        navigate('/', {replace:true})
      })
  }
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen'>
      <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
        <video src={shareVideo}
        type="video/mp4"
        loop
        muted
        autoPlay
        className='w-full h-full object-cover'
        />
        <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
            <div className='p-5'>
              <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" />
            </div>
            <div className='shadow-2x1'>
                <GoogleOAuthProvider 
                   clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}
                >
                  <GoogleLogin
                    onSuccess= {responseGoogle}
                    onError={() => {
                      console.log('Login Failed');
                    }}
                    cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
                  />; 
                </GoogleOAuthProvider>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

I got console error:-Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined.
I want to route to homepage but its not working.
[image]

i tried to use gapi

```js
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import shareVideo from '../assets/share.mp4';
import logo from '../assets/logowhite.png';
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { client } from '../client';
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}
  const initClient = () => {
    gapi.client.init({
      clientId: clientId,
      scope: "",
    });
  };
  gapi.load("client:auth2", initClient);
  const responseGoogle=(response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj))

    const {name, googleId, imageUrl} = response.profileObj;
    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: 'user',
      image: imageUrl,
      userName: name,  
    }
    client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      .then(() =>{
        navigate('/', {replace:true})
      })
  }
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen'>
      <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
        <video src={shareVideo}
        type="video/mp4"
        loop
        muted
        autoPlay
        className='w-full h-full object-cover'
        />
        <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
            <div className='p-5'>
              <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" />
            </div>
            <div className='shadow-2x1'>
                <GoogleOAuthProvider 
                   clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}
                >
                  <GoogleLogin
                    onSuccess= {responseGoogle}
                    onError={() => {
                      console.log('Login Failed');
                    }}
                  />; 
                </GoogleOAuthProvider>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

got console error Forced reflow while executing JavaScript.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Where does `response` come from? As the error states `response.profileObj` is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you check wath's inside the `response` with `console.log('response')` ? 
It seems that the key `profileObj` doesn't exist.

Comment: unfortunately the [package's docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) don't make clear what's in this `response` object (it has type `CredentialResponse` but I don't see a definition of that type and none of the code examples do anything to allow us to see what's inside it. You'll need to log it to the console to see what's there - but clearly there's no `profileObj`, so whatever information you need is probably stored under some different key.

Comment: on console logging response i get clientId, credentials, and                                                             [[Prototype]]
: 
Object
constructor
: 
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
: 
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
: 
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
: 
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
: 
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
: 
ƒ toString()
valueOf
: 
ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__
: 
ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
: 
ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
: 
ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
: 
ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__
:

Comment: @RobinZigmond i was trying to store the users who login to the database(sanity) and route to homepage. should I change the login package?